# Symfony2 Extending Controller getParameter()

Tags: php, symfony, extends

I Want to extend Symfony2 Controller to my project that is using API but I am having error of a non object use getParameter() function look at my code:

```
namespace Moda\CategoryBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var String 
     */
    protected $_host;

    /**
     * @var String
     */
    protected $_user;

    /**
     * @var String
     */
    protected $_password;

    public function __construct()
    {   
        $this->_host = $this->container->getParameter('api_host');
        $this->_user = $this->container->getParameter('api_user');
        $this->_password = $this->container->getParameter('api_password');

    }
}
```

And next Controller

```
namespace Moda\CategoryBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class CategoryController extends ApiController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/category", name="_category")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    { 
        return array('name' => 'test');
    }

}
```

And the end, I got this Fatal Error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getParameter()
>   on a non-object in (..)

I try to use $this->setContainer() but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea how can I slove this problem?

Comment: You could define ApiController as a Service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736598/symfony2-how-to-use-construct-in-a-controller-and-access-securty-context

Comment: @Calimero Yes, the theme is similar. But I do not understand the answer. You see what I want to do, whether in symfony is a way to do it? I tried to use setContainer but did not help.

Comment: answer is quite simple : you cannot use the container in the controller constructor. You have to work with another method to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  your controller is not defined as service, The constructor execution of the controller is not persisted.

You have two options to solve your situation:

1. Define the controller as a service and inject the parameters you need using dependency injection.
2. Add an init method in the controller, or on a parent abstract controller, and  call the init method, before the action you need to have these parameters available;

Answer (score 1):

You cant use container in Controller `__construct` at reason that when constructor called where is none container set yeat.

You can simply define some simple methods in controller like

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    protected function getApiHost()
    {
        return $this->container->getParameter('api_host');
    }
}
```

Comment: Even with injection of the container it still didn't worked worked in the constructor.
Currently just calling them in my normal functions, google for quite a time for this specific answer.
Is there nowadays a method known how to manage the parameters in a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if something crazy like this would work? Instead of overriding the constructor, override the setContainer method? I haven't tried it...just thinking out loud.

```
namespace Moda\CategoryBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class ApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var String
     */
    protected $_host;

    /**
     * @var String
     */
    protected $_user;

    /**
     * @var String
     */
    protected $_password;


    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        parent::setContainer($container);

        $this->_host = $this->container->getParameter('api_host');
        $this->_user = $this->container->getParameter('api_user');
        $this->_password = $this->container->getParameter('api_password');

    }
}
```